# how to use 3d model as a scene background in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Greeting, I want to use a 3d model as a scene background. how is it possible?

```
const assetsLoader = new GLTFLoader();
assetsLoader.load(monkeyURL.href, function (gltf) {
  const model = gltf.scene;
  scene.add(model);
  model.castShadow = true;
  model.position.set(10, 5, 15);
});
scene.background = assetsLoader.load(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. Like mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene) you can assign to `Scene.background`:

- A color for defining a uniform colored background.
- Textures defining a (flat) textured background.
- Environment maps for defining a skybox.